# Scala. Idiomatic flatten function implementation

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming

I am trying to implement flatten function in Scala.
I finished with something like this:

```
// implementation
def flatten(xs: List[Any]): List[Any] =
    xs match {
        case List() => List()
        case y::ys => y match {
            case k::ks => flatten(List(k)) ::: flatten(ks) ::: flatten(ys)
            case _ => y :: flatten(ys)
        }
    }
// something like tests
def main(args: Array[String]){
    val f1 = flatten(List(List(1, 1), 2, List(3, List(5, 8))))
    assert(f1 == List(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8))
    val f2 = flatten(List(List(List(1), List(1)), 2, List(3, List(5, 8))))
    assert(f2 == List(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8))
}
```

This implementation works but uses concatenation(it is slow I think). Can somebody provide(or explain) a solution without list concatenation?

I googled a little bit but most of question about built-in flatten

Comment: Throwing away types is not idiomatic ;-)

Comment: This is a better fit for codereview.se

Comment: @Daenyth, Please, describe your note. I have an atomic problem which I correctly described and illustrate with code sample. What is the reason to move it somewhere?

Comment: @om-nom-nom, please describe your idea. Is it better to change function to generic?

Comment: As best I can understand it, your question here is `This implementation works but looks ugly. [...]`. That's pretty much the exact reason that CR was created. From the SO faw: [You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). This question is looking for more open ended discussion - SO chat might be another good place

Comment: It's practical question. It's based on actual problem. And it's answerable. I think there are two possible answer: better solution without concatenation or grounded note about absence of this kind of solution

Comment: I'm pretty sure the canonical practical answer to this question as a practical problem is `Use the built in flatten instead of this`. I'm also pretty sure that's of questionable usefulness to you

Comment: Take a look at the [built-in implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.1/src/library/scala/collection/generic/GenericTraversableTemplate.scala#L169). It uses a builder and not list concatenation. It also requires a function that maps the elements to `GenTraversableOnce`, rather than doing pattern matching (this lets it flatten List[Option[_]] and such). However, unlike your function, it only flattens one level deep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, as @om-nom-nom pointed out, there is really no point in talking about anything being idiomatic without addressing the `List[Any]`. Let's see if we can describe this in a better way.

```
sealed trait Tree[A]
case class Node[A](l: List[Tree[A]]) extends Tree[A]
case class Leaf[A](a: A) extends Tree[A]

def flatten[A](tree: Tree[A]): List[A]
```

It becomes a bit easier to fill in the blanks now.

```
def flatten[A](tree: Tree[A]): List[A] = {
  def flattenRec(acc: List[A], t: Tree[A]): List[A] = t match {
    case Leaf(a) => a :: acc
    case Node(ll) => ll.foldLeft(acc)(flattenRec)
  }
  flattenRec(Nil, tree).reverse
}
```

However, if we add some additional capability to our `Tree` using scalaz, then this becomes easier, and in fact may help you do whatever you wanted to do with the flattened list of lists. Here I am providing a definition of `scalaz.Foldable[Tree]`.

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

object Tree {
  implicit def treeFoldable = new Foldable[Tree] {
    override def foldMap[A, B](fa: Tree[A])(f: (A) => B)(implicit F: Monoid[B]): B = {
      fa match {
        case Leaf(a) => f(a)
        case Node(l) => l.foldLeft(F.zero)((acc, tree) => F.append(acc, foldMap(tree)(f)))
      }
    }

    override def foldRight[A, B](fa: Tree[A], z: => B)(f: (A, => B) => B): B = fa match {
      case Leaf(a) => f(a, z)
      case Node(l) => l.foldRight(z)((tree, zz) => foldRight[A, B](tree, zz)(f))
    }
  }
}
```

Now our flatten becomes simply

```
def flatten2[A](tree: Tree[A]): List[A] = {
  Foldable[Tree].foldLeft(tree, List.empty[A])((acc, a) => a :: acc).reverse
}
```

or using the foldable syntax imports

```
def flatten2[A](tree: Tree[A]): List[A] = {
  tree.foldLeft(List.empty[A])((acc, a) => a :: acc).reverse
}
```

If we had `Tree[Int]` we could sum all of the values

```
val numbers: Tree[Int] = Node(List(Leaf(1), Node(List(Leaf(2), Leaf(3))), Leaf(4)))
val sum = numbers.foldLeft(0)(_ +  _)
```

As it turns out, scalaz has a very similar [Tree](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Tree.scala) already, something I've found incredibly useful. The difference is that scalaz.Tree contains an `A` with each `Node[A]`.